# I want to display json data in picker in react native. I'm using functional based component not class based. Is there any solution?

Tags: react-native

```
<View style={styles.SectionStyling}>
  <Picker
    selectedValue={userNetwork}
    style={styles.inputStyle}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
    underlineColorAndroid="#FFFFFF"
    blurOnSubmit={false}
  >
    <Picker.Item label="Select Network" value="select network" />
    <Picker.Item label="Jazz/Warid" value="MOBILINK" />
    <Picker.Item label="Zong" value="ZONG" />
    <Picker.Item label="Telenor" value="TELENOR" />
    <Picker.Item label="Ufone" value="UFONE" />
    <Picker.Item label="SCO" value="SCO" />
  </Picker>
```

Comment: hie ! Hashim! can you provide a bit more context in the description of the code, and what package are you using for picker

Comment: How's your JSON formatted?